# Modify existing war with GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt, compilation, project, war

I have a war file. In this file i have found the source files (that is the .java).
After I modify these files i would like to obtain a new war file. 
Notice that web-app contains user interface generated by GWT. 
I don't know how to recreate the html files.
Note that I haven't the pom files of the project.
This is a Dynamic web project and not a GWT project.

I'm sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two things here.

You have server side code which runs in Java. Those are Servlets, EJB, Spring code or something similar, depending on your project. If you changed a server side class, you have to recompile and place the resulting *.class* file in the right place (*WEB-INF/classes*).

However if you changed something in the client side code. The GWT components you did mention. Things get a bit more complicated. You have to rebuild the client using the GWT compiler. The GWT compiler produces a set of *.html*, *.js* and *.css* files. Those files go into the package then.

It is probably best if you read up on how [web applications are structured](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html) and how to [organize GWT projects](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html). Then setup a proper project with the code you got.